# How to find relative hours and relative days to a particular date in hive

Tags: sql, hive

[image: Sample data fields]

I am trying to solve a problem where I have to find relative hours and relative days to a particular event on a day (for example 5 hours before the event or 5 days before the event day). I have got a timestamp field with the starting time of the event and another timestamp field with request times of various actions before the event!

I tried using

```
(CASE WHEN event_id IS NOT NULL
     THEN ROUND((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(request_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time_utc))/ 3600.0,2) 
     ELSE NULL
 END) AS relative_time_hours, 
(day(b.start_time_utc)-day(a.action_request_time)
) AS relative_time_days
```

Comment: You tried - and what? Do you have any errors?

Comment: I am able to get the hours but I want the clock to be tracked for actions that occurred within 48 hours of the event, right now its just tracking 24 hours ! Also I get  Null for the relative days